# jquery-socialist giving 400 error for Twitter

Tags: jquery, twitter

I Integrated **jquery-socialist.js** in my application. 
But for Twitter is giving error:

```
{"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]}
```

URL is below:

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitterapi&count=2?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=|id|&count=|num|

Answer (score 0):

Find an other library. https://github.com/iatek/jquery-socialist tells me:

> This project is no longer being maintained due to most social API's no
>   requiring OAuth and some level of server-side authentication. The
>   original intent of this project was solely browser-side JavaScript.

Comment: Actually for social integration i am using above library. Do you have any solution ?

Comment: Depends on your needs. I thinks Google will help you find the right one.